# Create a new view in directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sublimetext

I have the following sublime view: https://www.flickr.com/photos/113328996@N07/16150493365/

I would like to add another layout file next to "application.html.erb". I'm currently stuck on how to do this.

I tried adding `touch app/views/layouts/name` but that doesn't work. Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can right click on layouts dir and select `Add file` or `Add new file`.

[image]

If you want to use `touch` you'll have to specify full path.

Example: `touch ~/Projects/MyProj/app/views/layouts/name.html.erb`